# AWS SDK (typescript) over corporate proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, sdk

I´m behind a corporate proxy and working on a Ubuntu@WSL2 (Windows10).
From there I´m trying to connect to aws via aws v3 sdk

On the windows machine a px proxy is running and I can connect to it over

```
http://169.254.254.1:3128/
```

Thus my env variable are set to this proxy

```
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,wsl.host,169.254.254.1
https_proxy=http://169.254.254.1:3128/
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,wsl.host,169.254.254.1
HTTPS_PROXY=http://169.254.254.1:3128/
HTTP_PROXY=http://169.254.254.1:3128/
http_proxy=http://169.254.254.1:3128/
```

curl is working

```
curl https://sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com -vvv
* Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'localhost,127.0.0.1,wsl.host,169.254.254.1'
* Uses proxy env variable https_proxy == 'http://169.254.254.1:3128/'
*   Trying 169.254.254.1:3128...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 169.254.254.1 (169.254.254.1) port 3128 (#0)
.
.
.
 
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
```

Now, the problem:

```
import { fromIni } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers"
import { myConfig } from '../central/GlobalConfig';

import { addProxyToClient } from 'aws-sdk-v3-proxy'
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";



const iniProvider = () => {
    return fromIni({
        profile: "profile-name" <everything is ok with that, too>
    })
}


const awsClientConfig = {
    credentialDefaultProvider: iniProvider,
    region: "eu-central-1"
}


export const s3Client = addProxyToClient(new S3Client(awsClientConfig), {debug:true});


.
.
.
.
const command = new ListBucketsCommand({});

  try {
    const { Owner, Buckets } = await s3Client.send(command);
.
.
.
```

I left out certain parts, because they are not important to say what I want to say :-)
The "send" leads finally to:

```
Setting http proxy to http://169.254.254.1:3128/ and https proxy to http://169.254.254.1:3128/
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  '$metadata': { attempts: 1, totalRetryDelay: 0 }

}
```

and I have no clue what so ever why node can´t connect. It doesn´t use that proxy. I saw that in the proxy debug logs on host (windows) side :-(

Anyone have a clue what I can do here ?

Many thanks and Greetings folks!

UPDATE: I guess it has to do with the name resolution. Anyone knows how to tweak the name resultion in amazon´s sdk?
You can do it in HTTP-Agent, but that´s encapsulated in the sdk :-(